# Please provide me an example of a religious violence that was rooted at ethnic conflict

Tags: religion, war

Please provide me an example of a religious violence that was rooted at ethnic conflict.

Did Armenian and Turkish conflict have religious reasons or ethnic reasons?

Did Tamil and Sinhalese conflict (Srilanka) have religious reasons or ethnic reasons?

Comment: While I agree with the premise of your question, the example you give is very controversial and is a more extreme example of what you are asking.  Can you either be more general as to what you are looking for or provide another example?

Comment: I am going to close this question because the way it is worded is more likely to result in opinions and specualtion, which is not acceptable. The two actual questions could perhaps be posed separately as two different questions by asking what documentation exists to support the notion that either conflict happened because of religion or ethnicity. I would strongly suggest creating two new questions along those guidelines.

Comment: This is an example of terrorism.

Comment: "please provide" doesn't fit this format, we're not here to do your homework or to satisfy your vague curiosity. We're here to help you with problems you have. If you did _try_ to search an answer to your question, and failed, then yes you are free to ask it here. Properly.

Comment: @BROY, *what* is an example of terrorism?  The Armenian genocide?  The fighting in Sri Lanka?  The way your question is being handled?

Comment: @Lohoris, then why T.E.D. has given me an acceptable answer? What was in his mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. This is effectively asking, "please give an example of violence in History". You'd be hard-pressed to find any example of religious violence that didn't have some kind of cultural-ethnic underpinning.

One of my favorite examples is [Arianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arianism). This was a difference with the Pope in Rome over the precise nature of the Holy Trinity which even most devout Christians are hard-pressed to explain.

However, when German tribes were conquering the western half of the Roman empire, having a slightly heretical faith became rather convenient. It allowed them to still effectively be Christians to their new subjects, but to not have to subject themselves to the authority of the Pope. In other words, it allowed them to keep their separate identity as Germans.

Once they became established (and amalgamated into the local population), they generally dropped Arianism.

Moving to more recent history, I'm sure most of you know about the big kerfuffle between the Catholics and the Protestants in Northern Ireland. What isn't typically reported is that the Catholics there are typically descended from native Irish peoples, while the Protestants are descendents of Scottish folk who migrated to Ireland centuries earlier.

There are of course oodles of modern examples. For instance, East Timor: Catholic (to Indonesia's Muslim), but also Tetum-speaking where Indonesia's official language is a flavor of Malay. They also spent several centuries as a Portuguese colony, and developed a unique culture different from the rest of Indonesia.

Look under the hood of most of the Christian/Islamic conflicts in sub-Saharan Africa, and you will see ethnic and/or cultural (eg: farming vs. herding) differences as well.

Religion is just part of a society's cultural package, so it is inevitable that when cultures clash, religion will come into it.

Answer (score 4):

Posting as an answer because I can't post a comment:

This is an absolutely terrible question that should be closed. It is far too open-ended as it asks for a list of undefined extent.

It clearly violates both of these items in the FAQ:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

It also fails to satisfy the main guideline in the FAQ:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

The OP should read the FAQ carefully before asking any more questions here.

Comment: That last FAQ quote has to be a cut-and-paste error. History is not about "actual problems that you face". If it were, we'd have to close 95% of the questions posted here.

Comment: I totally agree to T.E.D..